# Create a local database file with PostgreSQL in Python

Tags: python, postgresql

Is there a way to create a *.db* file with PostgreSQL and connect to it?
I haven't found anything on the Internet in this regard.
It seems like it is only possible to access a database with user, password, host etc. But I dont want that.

For example the equivalent in SQLite is:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
```

Comment: Postgres does not work like that, there are no `.db` files.

Comment: They are both SQL databases, but there modes of operation are different. SQLite is a single file database that is generally embedded in an application. Postgres is a client/server database that listens on a host for multiple users/applications to connect.  If you want SQLite behavior then you need to use it or some other embedded database.